# What is the to solve this recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_n+5a_{n-1}-6a{n-2}=14-2^{n+1}$
So the homogeneous part is: $C_1+C_2\cdot(-6)^n$.
But I can't find the particular solution.

My attempt:

$x_n^p=x_n^{p_1} + x_n^{p_2}$ where $x_n^{p_1} = 14$ and $x_n^{p_2} = 2^{n+1}$.

My ansatz for the first one:

$B+5B-6B=14\implies 0=14$

For the second one:
$A\cdot2^n+5\cdot A\cdot 2^{n-1}-6\cdot A\cdot 2^{n-2}=2^{n\cdot2}\implies A=1$

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: The homogeneous part contains a constant solution so you need to guess $a_n^p=C_3\cdot n+C_4\cdot2^n$

Comment: I say thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean $a_n+5a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$A_n+5A_{n-1}=16+6an-2^{n+1}~~~(`)$$
First Solve $$A_n+5A_{n-1}=0~~~~~(2).$$ Take $A_n=\lambda^{n} \implies 1+5/\lambda=0 \implies \lambda=-5.$
So $A_n=(-5)^n$ is the solution of the homogeneous part (2).
Next, to solve $$A_n+5A_{n-1}=-2^{n+1}~~~(3)$$ Take $A_n=c 2^n$ in (2), we get $c=-4/7$. Sn $A_n=-2^{n+2}/7$ is the solution of (3).
Next, to solve $$A_n+5A_{n-1}=16+16an~~~(4).$$
Take $A_n=pn+q$ in (4), we get $p=a$ and $q=8/3+5a/6$.
So $A_n=an+8/3+5a/6$ is the solution of (4).
Finally, the solution of $(1)$ is given by
$$A_n=(-5)^n-2^{n+2}/7+an+8/3+5a/6$$